# Yandex Disk API can't make request with access token node.js

Tags: node.js, yandex, yandex-api

I successfully generated an access token but now I can't use it. Sadly there is no official yandex node library for using the API. There are 2 unofficial npm module that will only work with a server but I want it localhost. As example with code like this, in this case I want to display all files from my disk. Of course I enabled all scopes for my app

```
request.get('https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/files/', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ 
if(err) {
console.log('err: ' + err)
}
console.log('body: ' + body)
});
```

Also if I would use https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/files?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
or https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/files?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
in my browser I would get
{"message":"?? ???????????.","description":"Unauthorized","error":"UnauthorizedError"}

Somebody has working code or an idea why I´am getting this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'm using [yandex-disk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yandex-disk) package. It works enougth for my purposes.

That my steps:

1. [Register app](https://oauth.yandex.ru/client/new) in Yandex Oath Service.
   After that I can [get info](https://oauth.yandex.ru/client/[YourAppClientID]/info) about my app
2. Realize the access method to get Oath Token [by calling this](https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=[YourAppClientID]).
3. npm i yandex-disk
4. Inserting the code into index.js

   ```
   const YandexDisk = require('yandex-disk').YandexDisk;
   const disk = new YandexDisk('YourOathTokenHere');
   console.log('disk', disk);
   disk.readdir('/', (err, response) => {
       console.log('callback error', err);
       console.log('callback response', response);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just include authorization header like that:

```
axios.get(encodeURI(`https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=${path}`), {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `OAuth ${token}`
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```